# Can i do several calculations in one calculation field?

Tags: tableau-api

Can i use calculation field for a multiple simple calculations?

Can't find it in documentation

SUM([Au 1])/SUM([AU])

SUM([Be 1])/SUM([BE])

syntax error

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: The result of any calculation needs to be a single value...

Answer (score 0):

You can reference calculations from other calculated fields, but you cannot have multiple results with the same calculated field.

The example below works:

```
Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3
 1.00 |  1.00 |  2.00
```

Calculated Field: Ratio of Col 1 & Col 2
SUM([Col 1]) / SUM([Col 2]) = 1

Calculated Field: Ratio of Col 1 & Col 3
[Ratio of Col 1 & Col 2] / SUM([Col 3]) = 0.5

The example below will not work:

```
Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3
 1.00 |  1.00 |  2.00
```

Calculated Field: Ratio of Col 1 & Col 2 & Col 3
SUM([Col 1]) / SUM([Col 2])

SUM([Col 1]) / SUM([Col 3]) = Error

You could do this instead:

```
Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3
 1.00 |  1.00 |  2.00
```

Calculated Field: Ratio of Col 1 & Col 2 & Col 3
(SUM([Col 1]) / SUM([Col 2])) / SUM([Col 3]) = 0.5

Hope this helps.